# Real Analysis for a High School Exam

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I am actually looking for good source for revising real analysis theorems as it is required in minute quantities for a math entrance exam. I read Bartle and Sherbert till Differentiation. However, due to engagement in other subjects in my school curriculum, I have lost touch with it and I really need to revise it for my exams. I also need a good collection of difficult problems so that I could learn as well as see good use of them. Here are problem samples so that you could tell me what I want:

1.(a) Suppose $f ◦ f = f$ . Then for each x, one must have $f ′(x) =......$ or $f ′(f (x)) =.... .$
Complete the sentence and justify.
(b) For a non-constant $f$ satisfying $f ◦ f = f$ , it is known and you may assume that the
range of $f$ must have one of the following forms: $\mathbb{R}, (−∞, b], [a, ∞), [a, b]$. Show that
in fact the range must be all of $\mathbb{R}$ and deduce that there is a unique such function f .
(Possible hints: For each $y$ in the range of $f$ , what can you say about $f (y)$? If the
range has a maximum element $b$ what can you say about the derivative of $f$ ?)
(c) Suppose that $g ◦ g ◦ g = g$ and that $g ◦ g$ is a non-constant function. Show that $g$ must
be onto, $g$ must be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing and that there is a unique
such increasing $g$. (CMI-2023)

2.[image: CMI-2022]

[image]

I would be gald if you could help.

Comment: Elementary analysis by Ross (I read the 2nd Edition) might help you.

Comment: Do you actually mean "high school" (used in your title), or did you perhaps mean "university"? Even so, this seems rather strange, since at least in the U.S. one doesn't study real analysis until the last year or two of undergraduate college/university education, and even then usually only those majoring in math or a closely related field.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, it is a high school exam. I don't know, recently the questions have been framed like this and a lot of students who appeared for the exam actually have read a little  bit of analysis as the exam demands rigorous proofs in its answers.